# Eshell - ./hello command not found(gcc)

Tags: emacsclient, eshell, c

**emacs** was installed by **Msys32** on Win7 32bit!

[image]
[image]

- **gcc** can't run *hello.c* on **eshell** but on **minibuffer**, Why?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: According to the output of your second `ls`, the executable is `hello.exe`, not `hello`.

Comment: @xuchunyang Please post that as an answer. Afterwards the OP should accept that answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @Tobias May I ask what 'OP' means?

Comment: @Shynur OP: Original Poster

Answer (score 2):

As my comment said, the executable is `hello.exe`, not `hello`, thus you should use `./hello.exe` instead.